# Recursive map function on tree type

Tags: functional-programming, f#

Suppose I have the following tree type:
`type T<'a> = N of 'a * T<'a> list`

How do I declare a recursive map function for it? Currently I have this, but it's an infinite loop:

```
let rec map f (N(a,sbs)) = 
    match sbs with
    | [] -> N(f a,[])
    | sbs' -> map f (N(a,sbs'))
```

I'd appreciate a hint.

Comment: Why do you call this a tree type when the definition appears to be a list?
Good hints in the answer: use a helper function with an accumulator.

Comment: It is a tree type with a variable number of subtrees. Anyway, I got the answer.

Comment: I see, so `sbs` is like `subtrees` (or `children`). Guess I'm used to working in larger (more people) codebases with longer names.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint. It's a tail-recursive map function.

```
    let mapTR f l =
        let rec loop acc = function
            | [] -> List.rev acc
            | x::xs -> loop (f x::acc) xs
        loop [] l
```